# ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework - entity relationship problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have problems defining an entity with my models.

My models are:

```
public class Airport
{
    [Key]
    public int AirportId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
    public List<Flight> DepartingFlights {get; set;}
    public List<Flight> ArrivingFlights {get; set;}
}

public class Flight
{
    [Key]
    public int FlightId {get; set;}
    public int Distance {get; set;}
    public float Duration {get; set;}
    public Airport DepartureAirport {get;set;}
    public Airport ArrivalAirport {get;set}
}
```

I have also tried to add entities in `dbContext` like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Flight>()
                .HasOne(f => f.DepartureAirport)
                .WithMany(a => a.DepartingFlights);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Flight>()
                .HasOne(f => f.ArrivalAirport)
                .WithMany(a => a.ArrivingFlights);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Airport>()
                .HasMany(a => a.DeparturingFlights)
                .WithOne(f => f.DepartureAirport);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Airport>()
                .HasMany(a => a.ArrivingFlights)
                .WithOne(j => j.ArrivalAirport);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

With this approach I get an error:

> Cannot create, drop, enable, or disable more than one constraint, column, index, or trigger named 'FK_flights_airports_DepartureAirportId' in this context. Duplicate names are not allowed.
> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'DepartureAirportId' in table 'flights' is specified more than once.

How could this problem be solved?

Comment: Refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476618/ef-code-first-one-to-many-twice-to-same-collection-type), it only needs to config once.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to define the one-to-many relationship once,

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      modelBuilder.Entity<Flight>()
                .HasOne(f => f.DepartureAirport)
                .WithMany(a => a.DepartingFlights);
      modelBuilder.Entity<Flight>()
                .HasOne(f => f.ArrivalAirport)
                .WithMany(a => a.ArrivingFlights);
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```